# Is there a way to enable row editing on only new added rows within a Kendo grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid, row, edit

So I have a standard Kendo grid in MVC with 2 non-editable columns. What I would like to achieve is to enable editing of all columns **only within the newly added rows**.

Example: There's 4 rows already in the grid, first 2 columns non-editable. User clicks "Add new", a new record appears in the grid with everything editable.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the word MVC in your question text. I'll leave my answer below, hopefully you can adapt it. Unfortunately, I don't have a workable MVC project to hand. In future, could you please also tag your question `kendo-asp.net-mvc` or `asp.net-mvc`

Comment: Added, thank you and sorry. Will test it out see if it works.

Comment: No worries. If you can't get it working, please post your MVC and I'll take a look. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an [editable](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.editable) function handler to your column definition, something like this:

```
{
  field: "salary",
    editable: function (dataItem) {
      return dataItem.isNew();
    }
}
```

Please note: you will need to have specified an `id` column in your model definition for this to work, for details see [isNew](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model/methods/isnew) documentation:

> Checks if the Model is new or not. The id field is used to determine if a model instance is new or existing one. If the value of the field specified is equal to the default value (specified through the fields configuration) the model is considered as new.